# How to change output filename in ffmpeg batch?

Tags: ffmpeg, windows

I'm using windows and ffmpeg to convert video mp4 into audio mp3. I've come up with the following batch line that will do the job:

```
 for %f in (*.mp4); do ffmpeg -i %f -vn -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 32k -f mp3 %f.mp3
```

However, the `%f` variable captures the whole filename with the extension, so my output looks like `filename.mp4.mp3`. I'd rather it look like `filename.mp3`.

I've tried all sorts of brackets and truncation methods I know of but I cannot get anything to work.

How can I change the filenames in an ffmpeg batch conversion on Windows?

Comment: For users looking for a Linux solution see [Batch conversion into a new folder with ffmpeg](http://video.stackexchange.com/a/19862/1760).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the file name directly from the `for` replacement parameter. No need to set a new variable at all.

```
for %f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%f" -vn -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 32k -f mp3 "%~nf.mp3"
```

If you want to do more complicated [string munging](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx), it's much more intuitive in Powershell:

```
ls *.mp4|foreach{
    ffmpeg -i $_ -vn -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 32k -f mp3 $_.name.replace("mp4", "mp3")
}
```

Comment: For the first solution, it says `set was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Powershell option seems to work. Perhaps I'll just use that. Thank you.

Comment: Dang, typo. I was on my mac so I couldnt' test it. Fixed now.

Comment: Output file name now comes out `%outfile.mp3`. It runs, which is certainly closer, but the output file naming is not working.

Comment: Another typo. It' been a while since I used batch scripting - I do everything in zsh and powershell. Try it again if you like, with luck it should work now..

Comment: I'm sorry, but it still doesn't work. I'm just on the regular Windows `cmd.exe`, aka "command line". The file comes out `%outfile%`. You don't have to keep working on this if you don't want to; I'm content with the Powershell solution. If I were to guess, the `outfile` variable is not being set or called correctly, or both. Or, the `%f` in this context is not a string of the name, which is how we are trying to use it. It is a pointer to the file.

Comment: I've asked on SO: [How to set and use filename string variables in cmd command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41813473/1934286)

Comment: The SO guys figured it out. An elegant solution. I've put in a suggested edit. The code `for %f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%f" -vn -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 32k -f mp3 "%~nf.mp3"` works.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [stib's answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/20475/3643), you can also put this command in a simple batch file. Just save the code below into a `.bat` file, move the file to the folder you want to work on, then double click it to run. This is assuming you've downloaded and set up ffmpeg.

```
@echo off
title Extract MP3 from MP4 with FFMPEG. 
rem Mono Channel, 32kbps.
for %%f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -vn -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 32k -f mp3 "%%~nf.mp3"
pause
```

Notice that the `%f` variables are now `%%f`. This is a batch file convention and is required. The script will not run if this is not changed. `title` is exactly that: the title of the script. `rem` is short for "remark": it is a comment and you can change that too. Neither lines are actually necessary.